# Financial Data From Webqueries in Excel

Tags: beginner, vba, excel, web-scraping

I'm new (to CR and to programming in general). I wrote my first VBA on Monday. This is my first working project. It Takes a bunch of financial data from a company called Financial Analytics and a bunch more from a number of webqueries, and puts it all in a nicely formatted table for external consumption.

It's a kludgy mess of stuff I've managed to make work, but I really have no idea what I'm doing. I imagine there'll be a lot of things to recommend so please feel free to only pick out a few things if it would take too long to review everything.

[My Project](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00537830941722939082)

Workbook_Open:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim StrTitle As String
Dim StrDateString As String
Dim StrDay As String
Dim StrMonth As String
Dim StrYear As String

StrDay = day(Date)
StrMonth = MonthName(month(Date))
StrYear = year(Date)

StrDateString = StrDay & " " & StrMonth & " " & StrYear
StrTitle = "Weekly Market Recap - " & StrDateString

Sheets("Market Dashboard").Activate
Cells(1, 1).Value = StrTitle

Dim StrFileDestination As String
Dim StrDateNumber As String

StrDateNumber = StrDay & "." & month(Date) & "." & StrYear
StrFileDestination = "S:\Investments\Regular Reports\Market Insight Reports\Weekly Dashboard\Client Facing Dashboard - " & StrDateNumber & ".xlsm"

Dim A As Long
Dim B As Long
Dim C As Long
Dim D As String
Dim E As String
Dim F As String
Dim G As String

A = 1

B = month(Date)
C = year(Date)

B = B - 3
If B <= 0 _
    Then
        B = B + 12
        C = C - 1
End If

D = B & "/" & A & "/" & C


B = B - 3
If B <= 0 _
    Then
        B = B + 12
        C = C - 1
End If

E = B & "/" & A & "/" & C


B = B - 3
If B <= 0 _
    Then
        B = B + 12
        C = C - 1
End If

F = B & "/" & A & "/" & C


B = B - 3
If B <= 0 _
    Then
        B = B + 12
        C = C - 1
End If

G = B & "/" & A & "/" & C

Cells(20, 12) = D
Cells(20, 13) = E
Cells(20, 14) = F
Cells(20, 15) = G

Cells(20, 20) = D
Cells(20, 21) = E

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=StrFileDestination

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub WebQuery_fx()

Dim oSh As Worksheet
Dim Sh1 As Worksheet
Dim Sh2 As Worksheet
Dim Sh3 As Worksheet

Dim filename As String
Dim fileloc As String

Dim counter As Integer
Dim cday As Integer
Dim cmonth As Integer
Dim cyear As Integer

Dim holder1 As String
Dim holder2 As String

Dim KillFileLoc As String ' for deleting file

    If Not Sheets("Market Dashboard").Cells(6, 24).Value > 0 Or Not Sheets("Market Dashboard").Cells(9, 24).Value > 0 _
        Then
            MsgBox "please input UBS CMCI Values in the indicated cells"
            Exit Sub
    End If

    If IsEmpty(Sheets("FE Performance Table").Cells(1, 1).Value) = True _
        Then
            MsgBox "Please paste FE performance data into the required sheet"
            Exit Sub
    End If

'Delete any residual data

Sheet3.Cells.Clear
Sheet4.Cells.Clear
Sheet5.Cells.Clear
Sheet6.Cells.Clear
Sheet7.Cells.Clear
Sheet8.Cells.Clear
Sheet9.Cells.Clear
Sheet10.Cells.Clear
Sheet13.Cells.Clear
Sheet17.Cells.Clear
Sheet18.Cells.Clear


'Perform web queries

Call webqueries


' copy data to dashboard

Call write_data

Sheet1.Range("T17:U17").Value = Sheet1.Range("T17:U17").Value

counter = 1
    Do While counter <= 4
        Columns(24).Delete
        counter = counter + 1
    Loop


' save

fileloc = "S:\investments\Market Insights\Weekly Dashboard"
cday = day(Date)
cmonth = month(Date)
cyear = year(Date)

    If cday < 10 Then holder1 = "0" & cday Else holder1 = cday
    If cmonth < 10 Then holder2 = "0" & cmonth Else holder2 = cmonth

filename = "\Client Facing Dashboard - " & holder1 & "." & holder2 & "." & cyear & ".pdf"

Sheet1.Activate
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=fileloc & filename

End Sub


Private Sub write_data()

Dim oSh As Worksheet
Dim Sh1 As Worksheet
Dim Sh2 As Worksheet
Dim Sh3 As Worksheet

' ranges are for group formatting output at the end

Dim range1 As Range
Dim range2 As Range
Dim range3 As Range
Dim range4 As Range
Dim range5 As Range
Dim range6 As Range
Dim bigrange As Range

Dim union As Range


' Write data to dashboard

' Write currency ($)

Set Sh1 = Sheet3
Set Sh2 = Sheet1

    With Sh1

        If .Range("A3").Text = "EUR" And .Range("A11").Text = "JPY" And .Range("A4").Text = "GBP" Then Else MsgBox "$ currency mismatch (1)"
        .Range("D3").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("S24") ' Dollars per euro
        .Range("C11").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("S25") ' Yen per Dollar
        .Range("D4").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("S23") ' Dollars per pound

        If .Range("E3").Text = "EUR" And .Range("E11").Text = "JPY" And .Range("E4").Text = "GBP" Then Else MsgBox "$ currency mismatch (2)"
        .Range("H3").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("t24") ' Dollars per euro
        .Range("G11").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("t25") ' Yen per Dollar
        .Range("H4").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("t23") ' Dollars per pound

        If .Range("I3").Text = "EUR" And .Range("I11").Text = "JPY" And .Range("I4").Text = "GBP" Then Else MsgBox "$ currency mismatch (3)"
        .Range("L3").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("u24") ' Dollars per euro
        .Range("K11").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("u25") ' Yen per Dollar
        .Range("L4").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("u23") ' Dollars per pound

    End With

' format start cells to yellow for verification

Sh1.Range("D3, D4, H3, H4, L3, L4, C11, G11, K11").Interior.ColorIndex = 6


' Write currency (£)

Set Sh1 = Sheet13
Set Sh2 = Sheet1

    With Sh1

        If .Range("A3").Text = "EUR" And .Range("E3").Text = "EUR" And .Range("I3").Text = "EUR" Then Else MsgBox "£ currency mismatch (1)"

        .Range("C3").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("S22") ' Euros per pound

        .Range("G3").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("T22") ' Euros per pound

        .Range("K3").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("U22") ' Euros per pound

    End With

' format start cells to yellow for verification

Sh1.Range("C3, G3, K3").Interior.ColorIndex = 6


' Write Libor

Set Sh1 = Sheet4
Set Sh3 = Sheet11

    With Sh1

        If .Range("B18").Text = " Current interest rates" Then Else MsgBox "libor mismatch (1)"
        If .Range("F18").Text = " First rate per month" Then Else MsgBox "libor mismatch (2)"

        .Range("C19").Copy Destination:=Sh3.Range("a8")
        .Range("G22").Copy Destination:=Sh3.Range("a9")
        .Range("G25").Copy Destination:=Sh3.Range("a10")
        .Range("G28").Copy Destination:=Sh3.Range("a11")

    End With



    With Sh3

        .Calculate

        .Range("b8").Copy
        Sh2.Range("K22").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        .Range("b9").Copy
        Sh2.Range("L22").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        .Range("b10").Copy
        Sh2.Range("M22").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        .Range("b11").Copy
        Sh2.Range("N22").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    End With

' format start cells to yellow for verification

Sh1.Range("C19, G22, G25, G28").Interior.ColorIndex = 6


' Write Euribor

Set Sh1 = Sheet5

    With Sh1

        If .Range("F8").Text = "Current rate (by day)" Then Else MsgBox "euribor mismatch (1)"
        If .Range("H8").Text = "Rate on first day of the month" Then Else MsgBox "euribor mismatch (2)"

        .Range("G9").Copy Destination:=Sh3.Range("a4")
        .Range("I12").Copy Destination:=Sh3.Range("a5")
        .Range("I15").Copy Destination:=Sh3.Range("a6")
        .Range("I18").Copy Destination:=Sh3.Range("a7")

    End With


    With Sh3

        .Calculate

        .Range("b4").Copy
        Sh2.Range("K23").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        .Range("b5").Copy
        Sh2.Range("L23").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        .Range("b6").Copy
        Sh2.Range("M23").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        .Range("b7").Copy
        Sh2.Range("N23").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    End With


' format start cells to yellow for verification

Sh1.Range("G9, I12, I15, I18").Interior.ColorIndex = 6


' Write Gilts

Set Sh1 = Sheet6

    With Sh1

        If .Range("A2").Text = "UK Gilt 2 Year Yield" And .Range("A4").Text = "UK Gilt 10 Year Yield" Then Else MsgBox "Gilt mismatch (1)"

        .Range("B2").Copy Destination:=Sh3.Range("A2")
        .Range("B4").Copy Destination:=Sh3.Range("A3")

    End With

    With Sh3

        .Calculate

        .Range("B2").Copy
        Sh2.Range("K24").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        .Range("B3").Copy
        Sh2.Range("K25").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    End With

' format start cells to yellow for verification

Sh1.Range("B2, B4").Interior.ColorIndex = 6


' Write Treasuries

Set Sh1 = Sheet7

    With Sh1

        If .Range("A11").Text = "10 Year" Then Else MsgBox "treasury mismatch (1)"

        .Range("B11").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("K26")

        ' format start cells for verification

        .Range("B11").Interior.ColorIndex = 6

    End With


' Write Bunds

Set Sh1 = Sheet8

    With Sh1

        If .Range("A4").Text = "Germany Bund 10 Year Yield" Then Else MsgBox "bund mismatch"

        .Range("B4").Copy Destination:=Sh3.Range("A1")

    End With

    With Sh3

        .Calculate
        .Range("B1").Copy
        Sh2.Range("K27").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    End With

    ' format start cells for verification

    Sh1.Range("B4").Interior.ColorIndex = 6



' Write S&P 500 (major indicies)

Set Sh1 = Sheet9

    With Sh1

        If .Range("A3").Text = "S&P 500 Index" Then Else MsgBox "Major indices mismatch (1)"

        .Range("B3").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("C12")

        ' format start cells for verification

        .Range("B3").Interior.ColorIndex = 6

    End With



' Write FTSE + Nikkei

Set Sh1 = Sheet10

    With Sh1

        If .Range("A2").Text = "FTSE 100" And .Range("A3").Text = "FTSE 250" And .Range("A11").Text = "Nikkei 225" Then Else MsgBox "FTSE + Nikkei mismatch (1)"

        .Range("B2").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("C10")
        .Range("B3").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("C11")
        .Range("B11").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("C13")

        ' format start cells for verification

        .Range("B2, B3, B11").Interior.ColorIndex = 6

    End With

' Write commodity index data

Set Sh1 = Sheet17

    With Sh2

        Set range1 = Sh1.Range("A1", "G27")

        .Range("S17").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("UBS Bloomberg CMCI", range1, 2, False)
        .Range("S10").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Crude Oil (WTI)", range1, 3, False)
        .Range("S11").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("RBOB Gasoline", range1, 3, False)
        .Range("S12").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("NYMEX Natural Gas", range1, 3, False)
        .Range("S13").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("COMEX Gold", range1, 3, False)
        .Range("S14").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("COMEX Silver", range1, 3, False)
        .Range("S15").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("COMEX Copper", range1, 3, False)
        .Range("S16").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("CBOT Corn", range1, 3, False)

    End With

'format start cells for verification

Sh1.Range("B3, C9, C11, C11, C16, C18, C19, C23").Interior.ColorIndex = 6

' Write gasoline performance data

Set Sh1 = Sheet18

    With Sh1

        If .Range("C1").Text = "3 Month" And .Range("e1").Text = "1-Year" Then Else MsgBox "Gasoline mismatch (1)"

        .Range("c2").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("T11")
        .Range("e2").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("U11")

    End With

' Write FE performance data

Set Sh1 = Sheet2
Sh1.Activate

Set range1 = Sh1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    With range1
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    With Sh1

        If .Range("A2").Text = "Index : Bloomberg Copper Sub GTR in GB" And .Range("A3").Text = "Index : Bloomberg Corn Sub GTR in GB" Then Else MsgBox "FE mismatch (1)"
        If .Range("A4").Text = "Index : Bloomberg Gold Sub GTR in GB" And .Range("A5").Text = "Index : Bloomberg Natural Gas Sub GTR in GB" Then Else MsgBox "FE mismatch (2)"
        If .Range("A6").Text = "Index : Bloomberg Silver Sub GTR in GB" And .Range("A7").Text = "Index : Bloomberg WTI Crude Oil Sub GTR in GB" Then Else MsgBox "FE mismatch (3)"

        If .Range("A8").Text = "DB X-Trackers II Iboxx £ Gilts UCITS ETF TR in GB" And .Range("A9").Text = "iShares $ Emerging Markets Corporate Bond UCITS ETF TR in GB" Then Else MsgBox "FE mismatch (4)"
        If .Range("A10").Text = "iShares $ High Yield Corporate Bond UCITS ETF TR in GB" And .Range("A11").Text = "iShares £ Corporate Bond 1-5yr UCITS ETF TR in GB" Then Else MsgBox "FE mismatch (5)"
        If .Range("A12").Text = "iShares £ Corporate Bond ex-Financials UCITS ETF TR in GB" And .Range("A13").Text = "iShares £ Index-Linked Gilts UCITS ETF TR in GB" Then Else MsgBox "FE mismatch (6)"

        If .Range("A14").Text = "iShares EURO Total Market Growth Large UCITS ETF TR in GB" And .Range("A15").Text = "iShares EURO Total Market Value Large UCITS ETF TR in GB" Then Else MsgBox "FE mismatch (7)"
        If .Range("A16").Text = "iShares FTSE 100 UCITS ETF Inc TR in GB" And .Range("A17").Text = "iShares FTSE 250 UCITS ETF TR in GB" Then Else MsgBox "FE mismatch (8)"
        If .Range("A18").Text = "iShares MSCI Emerging Markets UCITS ETF Acc in GB" And .Range("A20").Text = "iShares MSCI Europe ex-UK UCITS ETF TR in GB" Then Else MsgBox "FE mismatch (9)"
        If .Range("A21").Text = "iShares Nikkei 225 UCITS ETF in GB" And .Range("A22").Text = "iShares S&P 500 UCITS ETF Inc TR in GB" Then Else MsgBox "FE mismatch (10)"

        If .Range("A23").Text = "iShares STOXX Europe 600 Automobiles & Parts (DE) TR in GB" And .Range("A24").Text = "iShares STOXX Europe 600 Banks (DE) TR in GB" Then Else MsgBox "FE mismatch (11)"
        If .Range("A25").Text = "iShares STOXX Europe 600 Basic Resources (DE) TR in GB" And .Range("A26").Text = "iShares STOXX Europe 600 Chemicals (DE) TR in GB" Then Else MsgBox "FE mismatch (12)"
        If .Range("A27").Text = "iShares STOXX Europe 600 Construction & Materials (DE) TR in GB" And .Range("A28").Text = "iShares STOXX Europe 600 Financial Services (DE) TR in GB" Then Else MsgBox "FE mismatch (13)"
        If .Range("A29").Text = "iShares STOXX Europe 600 Food & Beverage (DE) TR in GB" And .Range("A30").Text = "iShares STOXX Europe 600 Health Care (DE) TR in GB" Then Else MsgBox "FE mismatch (14)"
        If .Range("A31").Text = "iShares STOXX Europe 600 Industrial Goods & Services (DE) TR in GB" And .Range("A32").Text = "iShares STOXX Europe 600 Insurance (DE) TR in GB" Then Else MsgBox "FE mismatch (15)"
        If .Range("A33").Text = "iShares STOXX Europe 600 Media (DE) TR in GB" And .Range("A34").Text = "iShares STOXX Europe 600 Oil & Gas (DE) TR in GB" Then Else MsgBox "FE mismatch (16)"
        If .Range("A35").Text = "iShares STOXX Europe 600 Personal & Household Goods (DE) TR in GB" And .Range("A36").Text = "iShares STOXX Europe 600 Real Estate (DE) TR in GB" Then Else MsgBox "FE mismatch (17)"
        If .Range("A38").Text = "iShares STOXX Europe 600 Retail (DE) TR in GB" And .Range("A39").Text = "iShares STOXX Europe 600 Technology (DE) TR in GB" Then Else MsgBox "FE mismatch (18)"
        If .Range("A40").Text = "iShares STOXX Europe 600 Telecommunications (DE) TR in GB" And .Range("A41").Text = "iShares STOXX Europe 600 Travel & Leisure (DE) TR in GB" Then Else MsgBox "FE mismatch (19)"
        If .Range("A42").Text = "iShares STOXX Europe 600 Utilities (DE) TR in GB" Then Else MsgBox "FE mismatch (20)"

        .Range("d2:e2").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("t15:U15") 'Copper
        .Range("d3:e3").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("t16:U16") 'corn
        .Range("d4:e4").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("t13:U13") 'Gold
        .Range("d5:e5").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("t12:U12") 'Natural Gas
        .Range("d6:e6").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("t14:U14") 'Silver
        .Range("d7:e7").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("t10:U10") 'Oil

        .Range("B8:F8").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("L10:P10")   'Gilts
        .Range("B9:F9").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("L15:P15")   'EM Debt (USD)
        .Range("B10:F10").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("L14:P14") 'High yield
        .Range("B11:F11").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("L12:P12") '1-5yr Corporate Bonds
        .Range("B12:F12").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("L13:P13") 'Corporate bonds
        .Range("B13:F13").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("L11:P11") 'Index Linked Gilts

        .Range("B14:F14").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D17:H17") 'European growth
        .Range("B15:F15").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D16:H16") 'European Value
        .Range("B16:F16").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D10:H10") 'Ftse 100
        .Range("B17:F17").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D11:H11") 'Ftse 250
        .Range("B18:F18").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D15:H15") 'Emerging Markets
        .Range("B20:F20").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D14:H14") 'Europe ex UK
        .Range("B21:F21").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D13:H13") 'Nikkei 225
        .Range("B22:F22").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D12:H12") 'S&P 500

        .Range("B23:F23").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D33:H33") 'Automobiles and Parts
        .Range("B24:F24").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D23:H23") 'Banks
        .Range("B25:F25").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D25:H25") 'Basic Resources
        .Range("B26:F26").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D31:H31") 'Chemicals
        .Range("B27:F27").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D38:H38") 'Construction and Materials
        .Range("B28:F28").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D36:H36") 'Fionancial Services
        .Range("B29:F29").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D27:H27") 'Food
        .Range("B30:F30").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D22:H22") 'Health
        .Range("B31:F31").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D34:H34") 'Industrials goods and Services
        .Range("B32:F32").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D28:H28") 'Insurance
        .Range("B33:F33").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D39:H39") 'Media
        .Range("B34:F34").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D26:H26") 'Oil and Gas
        .Range("B35:F35").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D35:H35") 'Personal and Household Goods
        .Range("B36:F36").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D29:H29") 'Real Estate
        .Range("B38:F38").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D40:H40") 'Retail
        .Range("B39:F39").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D32:H32") 'Technology
        .Range("B40:F40").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D30:H30") 'Telecommunications
        .Range("B41:F41").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D37:H37") 'Travel and Leisure
        .Range("B42:F42").Copy Destination:=Sh2.Range("D24:H24") 'Utilities

    End With

' Final formatting for dashboard

Sh2.Activate

    With Sh2

        Set bigrange = .Range("A6:V40")
        Set range1 = .Range("C10:H17")
        Set range2 = .Range("K10:P15")
        Set range3 = .Range("K22:O27")
        Set range4 = .Range("D22:H40")
        Set range5 = .Range("S10:U17")
        Set range6 = .Range("S22:U25")

    End With

Set union = Application.union(range1, range2, range3, range4, range5, range6)



' format data

bigrange.Hyperlinks.Delete
bigrange.Interior.ColorIndex = 2

union.NumberFormat = "#,##0.0"
range6.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"

' harmonise font, size etc.

bigrange.Font.Name = "Century Gothic"
bigrange.Font.Size = "10"
bigrange.Font.ColorIndex = 1
bigrange.VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
bigrange.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft

bigrange.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone

' underline headers
Range("C7:I7").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Range("C19:I19").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Range("K19:O19").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Range("K7:P7").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Range("S7:U7").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Range("S19:U19").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous

End Sub

Private Sub webqueries()

Dim oSh As Worksheet

Set oSh = Sheet3

Dim currentdate As String
Dim minus3months As String
Dim minus6months As String

Dim cday As Integer
Dim cmonth As Integer
Dim cyear As Integer
Dim holder1 As String ' day holder
Dim holder2 As String ' month holder

' find currency dates

cday = day(Date)
cmonth = month(Date)
cyear = year(Date)

    If cday < 10 Then holder1 = "0" & cday Else holder1 = cday
    If cmonth < 10 Then holder2 = "0" & cmonth Else holder2 = cmonth

currentdate = cyear & "-" & holder2 & "-" & holder1

cday = 1
cmonth = cmonth - 3

    If cmonth <= 0 _
        Then
            cmonth = cmonth + 12
            cyear = cyear - 1
                Else
                    ' nothing
    End If

        If cday < 10 Then holder1 = "0" & cday Else holder1 = cday
        If cmonth < 10 Then holder2 = "0" & cmonth Else holder2 = cmonth

minus3months = cyear & "-" & holder2 & "-" & holder1

cmonth = cmonth - 3

    If cmonth <= 0 _
        Then
            cmonth = cmonth + 12
            cyear = cyear - 1
                Else
                    ' nothing
    End If

        If cday < 10 Then holder1 = "0" & cday Else holder1 = cday
        If cmonth < 10 Then holder2 = "0" & cmonth Else holder2 = cmonth

minus6months = cyear & "-" & holder2 & "-" & holder1


' perform webqueries


With oSh.QueryTables.Add("URL;http://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=USD&date=" & currentdate, oSh.Range("A1"))
.BackgroundQuery = False
.TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
.SaveData = True
End With

With oSh.QueryTables.Add("URL;http://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=USD&date=" & minus3months, oSh.Range("E1"))
.BackgroundQuery = False
.TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
.SaveData = True
End With

With oSh.QueryTables.Add("URL;http://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=USD&date=" & minus6months, oSh.Range("I1"))
.BackgroundQuery = False
.TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
.SaveData = True
End With

MsgBox "Currency data ($) retrieved"

Set oSh = Sheet13

With oSh.QueryTables.Add("URL;http://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=GBP&date=" & currentdate, oSh.Range("A1"))
.BackgroundQuery = False
.TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
.SaveData = True
End With

With oSh.QueryTables.Add("URL;http://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=GBP&date=" & minus3months, oSh.Range("E1"))
.BackgroundQuery = False
.TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
.SaveData = True
End With

With oSh.QueryTables.Add("URL;http://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=GBP&date=" & minus6months, oSh.Range("I1"))
.BackgroundQuery = False
.TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
.SaveData = True
End With

MsgBox "Currency data (£) retrieved"

Set oSh = Sheet4
With oSh.QueryTables.Add("URL;http://www.global-rates.com/interest-rates/libor/british-pound-sterling/gbp-libor-interest-rate-3-months.aspx", oSh.Range("A1"))
.BackgroundQuery = False
.TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
.SaveData = True
End With

MsgBox "Libor data retrieved"

Set oSh = Sheet6
With oSh.QueryTables.Add("URL;http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/rates-bonds/government-bonds/uk", oSh.Range("A1"))
.BackgroundQuery = False
.TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
.SaveData = True
End With

MsgBox "Gilt data retrieved"

Set oSh = Sheet7
With oSh.QueryTables.Add("URL;http://finance.yahoo.com/bonds", oSh.Range("A1"))
.BackgroundQuery = False
.TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
.SaveData = True
End With

MsgBox "Treasury data retrieved"

Set oSh = Sheet8
With oSh.QueryTables.Add("URL;http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/rates-bonds/government-bonds/germany", oSh.Range("A1"))
.BackgroundQuery = False
.TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
.SaveData = True
End With

MsgBox "Bund data retrieved"

Set oSh = Sheet9
With oSh.QueryTables.Add("URL;http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/stocks/world-indexes", oSh.Range("A1"))
.BackgroundQuery = False
.TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
.SaveData = True
End With

MsgBox "S&P data retrieved"

Set oSh = Sheet5
With oSh.QueryTables.Add("URL;http://www.euribor-rates.eu/euribor-rate-3-months.asp", oSh.Range("A1"))
.BackgroundQuery = False
.TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
.SaveData = True
End With

MsgBox "Euribor data retrieved"

Set oSh = Sheet10
With oSh.QueryTables.Add("URL;http://shares.telegraph.co.uk/indices/?index=MCX", oSh.Range("A1"))
.BackgroundQuery = False
.TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
.SaveData = True
End With

MsgBox "FTSE & Nikkei data retrieved"

Set oSh = Sheet17

With oSh.QueryTables.Add("URL;http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/commodities/futures/", oSh.Range("A1"))
.BackgroundQuery = False
.TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
.SaveData = True
End With

MsgBox "Commodity index data retrieved"

Set oSh = Sheet18

With oSh.QueryTables.Add("URL;http://www.unitedstatescommodityfunds.com/performance.php?fund=uga&page=performance", oSh.Range("A1"))
.BackgroundQuery = False
.TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
.SaveData = True
End With

MsgBox "Gasoline returns data retrieved"

End Sub
```

Comment: Also, I recommend you come say hi in chat :) http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor

Comment: Could you post the file in a drop box? I'm a visual person - I like to see what the code is doing to the workbook. Call me Forrest if you like.

Comment: There's a link to tinyupload to download the workbook. Is that okay?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Option Explicit

```
Option Explicit
```

That should be in every VBA module you ever write. No excuses. Go to tools > Options > Require Variable Declaration and it will insert it for you automatically.

This is important because, without that statement. If I write:

```
dim Cell as range
    cel = range("A1")
```

Excel treats `cel` as an entirely different variable. And since you didn't define it, Excel assumes it's a variant (also dangerous). And suddenly you have a rogue variable in your program and another which isn't what you think it is.

Option explicit means if Excel encounters a variable you didn't explicitly declare using `dim` (or other equivalents) it will refuse to compile until you fix it. Automatically catching all your spelling mistakes (and also forcing you to declare your variable types, another good thing).

### Variable Naming

**This is a great start:**

> ```
> Dim StrTitle As String
> Dim StrDateString As String
> Dim StrDay As String
> Dim StrMonth As String
> Dim StrYear As String
> ```

It's clear what type of data should be in these variables and what they represent.

**This is not:**

> ```
> Dim A As Long
> Dim B As Long
> Dim C As Long
> Dim D As String
> Dim E As String
> Dim F As String
> Dim G As String
> ```

It is a pretty much universal convention in all programming that singular character variables (almost exclusively lowercase) are integers/longs, so:

```
dim i as long, j as long, k as long
```

is a perfectly normal coding practice, but:

```
dim D as string, E as string, F as string
```

most definitely is not.

Not only is it going to confuse and annoy any programmer reading your code (god help them if you leave your company and they actually have to maintain it) but it's just as likely to confuse you in a week/month/year when you come back to it and have no idea what your variables are or what they're doing.

[A good summary of Variable Naming best practices](http://codebuild.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/15-best-practices-of-variable-method.html). In general, the name of a variable should tell you, at a minimum, what **type** (string, long, boolean etc.) of data it holds, and **what** it is supposed to be.

> ```
> Dim StrTitle As String
> Dim StrDateString As String
> Dim StrDay As String
> ```

These are ok, but could be easily improved like so:

```
 Dim StrTableHeading As String
 Dim StrTodaysDateString As String
 Dim StrThisDay As String
```

now if you, or anyone else, sees one of those in the middle of a procedure, they'll know exactly what it is.

### Readable Code

> ```
>  B = B - 3 If B <= 0 _
>      Then
>          B = B + 12
>          C = C - 1 End If
>  
>  D = B & "/" & A & "/" & C
>  
>  
>  B = B - 3 If B <= 0 _
>      Then
>          B = B + 12
>          C = C - 1 End If
> ```

I haven't got a clue what this is or what it's supposed to be doing. I just have to blindly trust that it's doing what it's supposed to be. Good variable naming will go a long way here. Just replacing variables with **good, descriptive, names** gives the following:

```
lngMonth = lngMonth - 3
If lngMonth <= 0 _
    Then
        lngMonth = lngMonth + 12
        lngYear = lngYear - 1
End If

str3MonthsAgoDate = lngMonth & "/" & lngDay & "/" & lngYear


lngMonth = lngMonth - 3
If lngMonth <= 0 _
    Then
        lngMonth = lngMonth + 12
        lngYear = lngYear - 1
End If
```

At a glance, it becomes perfectly clear what it's doing. You're creating Date Strings for today, 3 months ago, 6 months ago etc.

### Refactoring

In simple language, Refactoring is splitting your Macro into lots and lots of smaller pieces (and sub-pieces etc.) that do little, specific things. E.G. your 5 lines to calculate the string for 3 months ago, could be a User-Created-Function that takes any date String and outputs the string from 3 months previously. (or just look up the [DateAdd() Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dateadd.php) :p )

Generally, any time you find yourself using copy/paste in your code, it's a good sign that what you just copied should be spun out as it's own sub/function. This is a [Good Overview of the concept](http://importblogkit.com/2015/05/how-do-you-eat-an-elephant/)

### Indentation

Another key aspect of readable code. Humans find it much easier to read down the page than across it. If you have loops, nesting, discrete steps etc. It's much clearer if they're all at different levels of indentation. For instance, your `Workbook_Open` reads much more clearly like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim StrTitle As String
    Dim StrDateString As String
    Dim StrDay As String
    Dim StrMonth As String
    Dim StrYear As String
    
    Dim StrFileDestination As String
    Dim StrDateNumber As String
    
        StrDateNumber = StrDay & "." & month(Date) & "." & StrYear
        StrFileDestination = "S:\Investments\Regular Reports\Market Insight Reports\Weekly Dashboard\Client Facing Dashboard - " & StrDateNumber & ".xlsm"
    
        StrDay = day(Date)
        StrMonth = MonthName(month(Date))
        StrYear = year(Date)
        
        StrDateString = StrDay & " " & StrMonth & " " & StrYear
        StrTitle = "Weekly Market Recap - " & StrDateString
        
    Sheets("Market Dashboard").Activate
        Cells(1, 1).Value = StrTitle
    
    Dim A As Long
    Dim B As Long
    Dim C As Long
    Dim D As String
    Dim E As String
    Dim F As String
    Dim G As String
    
        A = 1
        B = month(Date)
        C = year(Date)
        
        B = B - 3
            If B <= 0 _
                Then
                    B = B + 12
                    C = C - 1
            End If
            
            D = B & "/" & A & "/" & C
        
        
        B = B - 3
            If B <= 0 _
                Then
                    B = B + 12
                    C = C - 1
            End If
            
            E = B & "/" & A & "/" & C
        
        
        B = B - 3
            If B <= 0 _
                Then
                    B = B + 12
                    C = C - 1
            End If
            
            F = B & "/" & A & "/" & C
        
        
        B = B - 3
            If B <= 0 _
                Then
                    B = B + 12
                    C = C - 1
            End If
        
            G = B & "/" & A & "/" & C
    
        Cells(20, 12) = D
        Cells(20, 13) = E
        Cells(20, 14) = F
        Cells(20, 15) = G
        
        Cells(20, 20) = D
        Cells(20, 21) = E
        
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=StrFileDestination

End Sub
```

And suddenly, you can, at a glance **see** the discrete steps of the macro.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> If IsEmpty(Sheets("FE Performance Table").Cells(1, 1).Value) = True _
>     Then
> ```

`IsEmpty` returns a boolean value, so what you're saying here is `If True = True Then` or `If False = True Then`. When you think of it this way, you'll see that you can simplify this by simply saying `If IsEmpty(...) Then`.

> ```
> If Not Sheets("Market Dashboard").Cells(6, 24).Value > 0 Or Not Sheets("Market Dashboard").Cells(9, 24).Value > 0 _
> ```

I recommend making these named ranges and referencing them that way instead. It will greatly clarify the code, and as an added bonus, make your code less coupled to the exact location inside the worksheet. If you need to move these cells, you can simply make the named range point somewhere else. This way, your VBA code wouldn't have to change. As it is, you would have to hunt down every reference to these cells.

By the way, I really like that you explicitly call `.Value` on the range. ++ Good job there. Making the explicit call reduces confusion and bugs. With an implicit call, you run the risk of accidentally getting a reference to the range instead of the value itself. Yes, yes. Good call.

> ```
> fileloc = "S:\investments\Market Insights\Weekly Dashboard"
> ```

You have this filepath hardcoded in several locations. Define a module level constant for it so you only ever have to change it in one location.